# How to add user in ldap with "+" in in dn?

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am looking on a system and the user id and part of the dn is really the email address.  some of gmail accounts use + in the email address.  so how can I do a ldapadd for them.

sample john+smith@gmail.com

Comment: What programming language? Which API?

Answer (score 0):

If the '+' sign is part of the DN and not an indicator of a multi-valued DN, then the '+' sign must be escaped. An example of a multi-valued DN:

- `dn: cn=abc+uid=def,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com`

The above DN is *multi-valued*, that is, both the `cn` attribute and the `uid` attribute comprise the RDN. If the intent is to have a  '+' be part of the data, then that '+' must be escaped according to the rules established in [RFC 4514](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4514).